# FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory return array with different sorting in iphone 8

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-8

I am trying to get contents of directory by using following method.

```
let files: [String]? = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: self.targetDirectory)
```

It was working perfectly in all devices but in case of IPhone 8, i get results in different sorting.

For example, in case of iPhone 7+, i get following results.

```
Printing description of filterFiles:
▿ Optional<Array<String>>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
    - 0 : "0.m4a"
    - 1 : "1.m4a"
```

But in case of iPhone 8, i get following results:

```
Printing description of files:
▿ Optional<Array<String>>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
    - 0 : "1.m4a"
    - 1 : "0.m4a"
```

In both cases, results are same but sorting is different. Can anyone help me about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the NSFileManager documentation: "The order of the files in the returned array is undefined.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSFileManager` doesn't sort the list of files. But you can do it yourself using `sorted` method of `array`. The code will look like this:

```
let files: [String]? = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: self.targetDirectory)
let sortedFiles = files?.sorted()
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the original question, I suggested changing the immutable property files to a mutable property:

```
var files: [String]? = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: self.targetDirectory)

if files != nil {
    files = files?.sorted()
}
```

To answer using Swift 5.5:

If you're just looking for a system default sorted file list by file name you can use the following with a URL.  There is not a sorted method for atPath: calls in FileManager. Using this method provides a list of URLs to work with.  If you need the full path you can use the file[#].path method to get the path to a list item.

```
let targetDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.targetDirectory)

do {
    let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: targetDirectoryURL), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles).sorted { $0.path < $1.path }
} catch {
    print("An error occurred: \(error)")
}
```

If you want it sorted in reverse order, just change the order inside the closure.

```
let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: targetDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles).sorted { $1.path < $0.path }
```